# Use some files as a git submodule

Tags: android, git, git-submodules

Is it possible to make a git submodule that contains only a few files from the working tree of the main project I'm working on?

Say my current directory structure looks like:

```
.git
FolderA
    FileAA
    FileAB
FolderB
    FileBA
    FileBB
```

I want to have FolderA/FileAA and FolderB/FileBA as part of a submodule, while the rest as part of the main project.

Context: I'm working on an Android project that has an iOS counterpart. The team agreed that translations would be oficially handled in the Android format (strings.xml) and iOS translations would be auto-generated with an automated tool. In Android, translations are split among a set of folders for each language, but those folders might contain other files (such as style and color definitions in the case of the `values` folder). So the idea is to have all xml files relating to translations in a submodule that can be shared between platforms. In the case of iOS, it would reside in a separate folder, from which the automated tool will gather the translations and convert them in iOS style.

Comment: I would recommend having your translation in a separate module of your android application, which can be completely put in a separate git submodule